# How to download an entire folder from Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

So I recently signed up for Google Cloud unaware it was more for coding than typical online storage. So I backed up one of my flash drives before wiping it and now I cant retrieve the files to replace them on the flash drive. I've tried a few commands I've seen on other questions here but only receiving results of:

```
C:\Users\Johnny\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gsutil -m cp -r dir gs://backup85468523
CommandException: No URLs matched: dir
CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.
```

or

```
C:\Users\Johnny\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gsutil -m cp -R    gs://backup85468523
CommandException: Wrong number of arguments for "cp" command.
```

Comment: For those wanting to avoid installing local tools like `gsutil`, there is a way to **download files *and* folders** from Google Cloud Storage entirely in the browser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59567734/2441655

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading folders from Google Cloud Storage Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406729/downloading-folders-from-google-cloud-storage-bucket)

Answer (score 1):

The command should be in the form gsutil cp [OPTION]... src_url dst_url, with both source and destination directories, as detailed on the [cp - Copy files and objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) documentation page. Your command seems to lack the destination part. If you mean the local directory, you can indicate is with a dot "." .

Comment: Same error as OP. Adding `.` destination directory didn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this works, since it differs from the docs, but just removing `dir` worked fine:

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://backup85468523
```

Comment: Missing local directory argument at the end. Or just a "." for current directory.

`gsutil -m cp -r gs://backup85468523 .`

Answer (score 0):

`gsutil` is not the recommended CLI for Cloud Storage.
So, if someone want an updated command using `gcloud storage`, here is the command

```
gcloud storage cp --recursive gs://my-bucket/*
```

Source: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage/cp

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code to download a folder from google cloud storage to local folder

os.system('gsutil -m cp -R gcs-folder-path local-folder-path')