# Download folder with Google Cloud Storage Api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I tried to download a folder with Google Cloud Storage API. I checked [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects), and it works for a single file. I try to find another way to download the folder, do you know any way to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723502/how-to-download-an-entire-folder-from-google-cloud-platform/55941512#55941512

Comment: There is no API for downloading multiple objects.  You must write code to list them and download them invidually.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If there is no API for that, I think there is no choice other than this.