# Unable to read files from google cloud storage bucket from jupyter notebook running on data proc cluster

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I am working on a Data Proc Spark cluster with an initialization action to install Jupyter notebook. I am unable to read the csv files stored on the google cloud storage bucket, however I am able to read the same files when I work on Spark Shell

Below is the error code I am getting

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv("gs://dataproc-78r5fe64b-a56d-4f5f4-bcf9-e1b7t6fb9d8f-au-southeast1/notebooks/datafile.csv")

    FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-2457012764fa> in <module>
----> 1 data = pd.read_csv("gs://dataproc-78r5fe64b-a56d-4f5f4-bcf9-e1b7t6fb9d8f-au-southeast1/notebooks/datafile.csv")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, doublequote, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    676                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    677 
--> 678         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    679 
    680     parser_f.__name__ = name

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    438 
    439     # Create the parser.
--> 440     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    441 
    442     if chunksize or iterator:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    785             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    786 
--> 787         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    788 
    789     def close(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1012     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
   1013         if engine == 'c':
-> 1014             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1015         else:
   1016             if engine == 'python':

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1706         kwds['usecols'] = self.usecols
   1707 
-> 1708         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1709 
   1710         passed_names = self.names is None

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: File b'gs://dataproc-78r5fe64b-a56d-4f5f4-bcf9-e1b7t6fb9d8f-au-southeast1/notebooks/datafile.csv' does not exist
```

Location path for the CSV file

```
gs://dataproc-78r5fe64b-a56d-4f5f4-bcf9-e1b7t6fb9d8f-au-southeast1/notebooks/datafile.csv
```

I have also made sure that the csv file is stored in the same storage bucket as attached to the data proc and have made sure that the file is in UTF-8-Encoded csv format

Can anyone please help me how to read the files stored in google bucket from jupyter notebook running on a dataproc cluster in google cloud.

Kindly let me know if more information is required

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: What kernel are you using in Jupyter? Python or Spark?

Comment: I have actually tried using both the Kernels, Python and Py-Spark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason Spark can read from GCS is that we configure it to use the [GCS connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/tree/master/gcs) for paths that start with `gs://`. You probably want to use `spark.read.csv(gs://path/to/files/)` to read CSV file(s) into a Spark dataframe.

You can read and write to GCS using pandas, but it's a bit more complicated. [This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357352/read-csv-from-google-cloud-storage-to-pandas-dataframe) lists some options.

Side note: If you're using Pandas, you should use a [single node](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/single-node-clusters) cluster since pandas code will not be distributed across a cluster.

Comment: Thanks Karthik, Have been trying to find a solution for quite some time and I understand that pandas code would be distributed across cluster.

Comment: Pandas is *not* distributed across the cluster, unless you're using something like Dask.

Comment: Sorry There was a typo, I meant that I understand that pandas would not be distributed accross for cluster. And a lot of thanks for helping out with the issue.