# Reading CSV files from Google Cloud Storage using pandas

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-storage, dask

I am trying to read a bunch of CSV files from Google Cloud Storage into pandas dataframes as explained in [Read csv from Google Cloud storage to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357352/read-csv-from-google-cloud-storage-to-pandas-dataframe)

```
storage_client = storage.Client()

bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix)

list_temp_raw = []
for file in blobs:
    filename = file.name
    temp = pd.read_csv('gs://'+bucket_name+'/'+filename+'.csv', encoding='utf-8')
list_temp_raw.append(temp)

df = pd.concat(list_temp_raw)
```

It shows the following error message while importing gcfs. The packages 'dask' and 'gcsfs' have already been installed on my machine; however, cannot get rid of the following error.

```
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gcsfs\dask_link.py", line 
121, in register
dask.bytes.core._filesystems['gcs'] = DaskGCSFileSystem
AttributeError: module 'dask.bytes.core' has no attribute '_filesystems'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is some error or conflict between the `gcsfs` and `dask` packages. In fact, the `dask` library is not needed for your code to work. The minimal configuration for your code to run is to install the libraries ( I am posting its latest versions):

```
google-cloud-storage==1.14.0
gcsfs==0.2.1
pandas==0.24.1
```

Also, the `filename` already contains the `.csv` extension. So change the 9th line to this:

`temp = pd.read_csv('gs://' + bucket_name + '/' + filename, encoding='utf-8')`

With this changes I ran your code and it works. I suggest you to [create a virtual env and install the libraries and run the code there](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/index.html#windows):

Comment: Thanks. I have all three libraries installed. Does it matter if using conda instead of pip to create a new environment?

Comment: I don't think it will make a difference. I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This has been tested and seen to work from elsewhere - whether reading directly from GCS or via Dask. You may wish to try import of gcsfs and dask, see if you can see the `_filesystems` and see its contents

```
In [1]: import dask.bytes.core

In [2]: dask.bytes.core._filesystems
Out[2]: {'file': dask.bytes.local.LocalFileSystem}

In [3]: import gcsfs

In [4]: dask.bytes.core._filesystems
Out[4]:
{'file': dask.bytes.local.LocalFileSystem,
 'gcs': gcsfs.dask_link.DaskGCSFileSystem,
 'gs': gcsfs.dask_link.DaskGCSFileSystem}
```

As of https://github.com/dask/gcsfs/pull/129 , gcsfs behaves better if it is unable to register itself with Dask, so updating may solve your problem.

Comment: Note: gcsfs does a fine job listing filenames on the remote storage, you should not need to use the google client in addition.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. However, in my case, importing either of gcsfs or dask throws out the above-mentioned AttributeError. It's weird as I have both installed on my windows machine.

Comment: Mine is 0.2.1 which is the latest one.

Comment: Can you try by pip-installing from github master?

Answer (score 0):

Few things to point out in the text above:
bucket_name and prefixes needed to be defined.
and the iteration over the filenames should append the each dataframe each time. Otherwise it is the last one that gets concatenated.

```
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd

storage_client = storage.Client()

buckets_list = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
bucket_name='my_bucket'
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blobs = bucket.list_blobs()

list_temp_raw = []
for file in blobs:
    filename = file.name
    temp = pd.read_csv('gs://'+bucket_name+'/'+filename, encoding='utf-8')
    print(filename, temp.head())
    list_temp_raw.append(temp)

df = pd.concat(list_temp_raw)
```