# Getting AttributeError when checking the version of dependencies with pd.show_versions()

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I want to check version of the dependencies; But `pd.show_versions()` gives `AttributeError`.

Here is the full traceback:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c4c6bc0da956> in <module>
----> 1 pd.show_versions()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_print_versions.py in show_versions(as_json)
     97     for modname in deps:
     98         mod = import_optional_dependency(
---> 99             modname, raise_on_missing=False, on_version="ignore"
    100         )
    101         if mod:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py in import_optional_dependency(name, extra, raise_on_missing, on_version)
     88     """
     89     try:
---> 90         module = importlib.import_module(name)
     91     except ImportError:
     92         if raise_on_missing:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125                 break
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 
    129 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py in exec_module(self, module)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gcsfs\__init__.py in <module>
      2 
      3 from .core import GCSFileSystem
----> 4 from .dask_link import register as register_dask
      5 from .mapping import GCSMap
      6 from ._version import get_versions

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gcsfs\dask_link.py in <module>
    120 
    121 try:
--> 122     register()
    123 except ImportError as e:
    124     print(e)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gcsfs\dask_link.py in register()
    115             return PyarrowWrappedGCSFS(self)
    116 
--> 117     dask.bytes.core._filesystems['gcs'] = DaskGCSFileSystem
    118     dask.bytes.core._filesystems['gs'] = DaskGCSFileSystem
    119 

AttributeError: module 'dask.bytes.core' has no attribute '_filesystems'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What does `import gcsfs` give? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55003924

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with your installation of GCSFS. There seems to be a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55003924).

Try `conda install -c conda-forge gcsfs` or `pip install gcsfs` to reinstall GCSFS.