# How to create pandas dataframe from parquet files kept on google storage

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-cloud-storage, parquet

I need to create data frame using pandas library using parquet files hosted on a google cloud storage bucket. I have searched the documents and online examples but can't seem to figure out how to go about it.

Could you please assist me by pointing me towards the right direction?

I am not looking for a solution but for a location where I could look for further information so that I could devise my own solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You may use [gcsfs](https://github.com/dask/gcsfs) and [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/_modules/pyarrow/parquet.html#ParquetDataset) libraries to do so.

```
import gcsfs
from pyarrow import parquet

url = "gs://bucket_name/.../folder_name"
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem()

// Assuming your parquet files start with `part-` prefix
files = ["gs://" + path for path in fs.glob(url + "/part-*")]
ds = parquet.ParquetDataset(files, filesystem=fs)
df = ds.read().to_pandas()
```

Comment: suggest to do `"/*.parquet"` instead of `"/part-*"` to be more explicit.

Comment: can you help with this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75529064/how-to-load-multiple-partition-parquet-files-from-gcs-into-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 3):

You can read it with [pandas.read_parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html) like this:

```
df = pandas.read_parquet('gs:/bucket_name/file_name')
```

Additionally you will need `gcsfs` library and either `pyarrow` or `fastparquet` installed.

Don't forget to [provide credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) in case you access private bucket.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. It is close but there is an issue. The said method reads a parquet file - agreed but it if a folder has multiple parquet files - it doesn't work OR is it that some other option is to be added? Basically I will not know whether there would be a single parquet file or multiple, and that is what I need to achieve.

Comment: You can get a list of files in the bucket and then iterate over it with a loop and read files one by one. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54988092/12232507) for an example. I don't think there is a method to read the entire bucket at once.

Comment: I would recommend you to kindly update your last comment as answer and I shall accept it as there is no other alternative.