# Read parquet metadata with pandas from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I'm able to read a parquet file located on GCS thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357352/read-csv-from-google-cloud-storage-to-pandas-dataframe) answer (read the first answer). I used the `pd.read_parquet` function, with pyarrow engine. 
I'd like now to access the parquet metadata without download the data into the dataframe. Is it possible to do that with pandas?

Comment: Hi, I am also having a similar question. Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution, using `gcsfs` without Pandas:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import gcsfs

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=myprojectname)

f = fs.open(myfilepath)
myschema = pq.ParquetFile(f).schema

print(myschema)
```

Comment: How to make this work if you have partitioned data stored in multiple parquet files like here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75529064/how-to-load-multiple-partition-parquet-files-from-gcs-into-pandas-dataframe