# How to load multiple partition parquet files from GCS into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to read multiple parquet files stored as partitions from google cloud storage and read them as 1 single pandas data frame. As an example, here is the folder structure at `gs://path/to/storage/folder/`

[image]

And inside each of the `event_date=*`, there are multiple parquet files

So the directory structure is something like this -

```
--gs://path/to/storage/folder/
   ---event_date=2023-01-01/
      ---abc.parquet
      ---def.parquet
   ---event_date=2023-01-02/
      ---ghi.parquet
      ---jkl.parquet
```

I want to load this to pandas data frame and I used below code

```
import pandas as pd
import gcsfs
from pyarrow import parquet

url = "gs://path/to/storage/folder/event_date=*/*" 
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem()


files = ["gs://" + path for path in fs.glob(url)]
print(files)
data = parquet.ParquetDataset(files, filesystem=fs)
multiple_dates_df = data.read().to_pandas()
print(multiple_dates_df.shape)
```

But I get below error -

```
OSError: Passed non-file path: gs://path/to/storage/folder/event_date=2023-01-01/abc.parquet
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: can you have a look at this [code snippet](https://gist.github.com/lpillmann/fa1874c7deb8434ca8cba8e5a045dde2)

Comment: Hi @SathiAiswarya - it works when you have the gs_directory_path as 1 single parquet files but I want to load multiple parquet files.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72059752/3242418) solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems it is not possible  for pandas to read multiple parquet files stored under a gcs path,There is a bug raised for this at [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/36743), which is still open further progress can be tracked there.