# Cloud AI Platform Training Fails to Read from Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm trying to use Cloud AI Platform for training (gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training).
I created my bucket and am sure the training file is there (gsutil ls gs://sat3_0_bucket/data/train_input.csv).

However, my job is failing with log messsage:

```
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ktrain/text/data.py", line 175, in texts_from_csv
    with open(train_filepath, 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://sat3_0_bucket/data/train_input.csv'
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you share the part of the code where you read the file?

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably happening because *ktrain* tries to auto-detect the character encoding using `open(train_filepath, 'rb')` which may be problematic with Google Cloud Storage.  One solution is to explicitly provide the `encoding` to `texts_from_csv` as an argument so this step is skipped (default is None, which means auto-detect).

Alternatively, you can read the data in yourself as a *pandas* DataFrame using one of [these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50201179/13550699). For instance, *pandas* evidently supports GCS, so you can simply do this: `df = pd.read_csv('gs://bucket/your_path.csv')`

Then, using *ktrain*, you can use `ktrain.text.texts_from_df` (or `ktrain.text.texts_from_array`) to load and preprocess your data.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your suggestion worked, but it also required "gcsfs" to be installed via setup.py.  Error was: `ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'gcsfs'. The gcsfs library is required to handle GCS files Use pip or conda to install gcsfs.` Pandas: `gcsfs: necessary for Google Cloud Storage access (gcsfs >= 0.1.0).`