# Flutter cant load image from url

Tags: flutter

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following ImageCodecException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Failed to load network image.
Image URL: https://cdn.sportmonks.com/images/soccer/leagues/5.png
Trying to load an image from another domain? Find answers at:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images

When i try the demo URL https://picsum.photos/250?image=9 it is working but the url above is good so what can be the problem?

```
class ListRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final imageUrl;
  const ListRow({Key key, this.name, this.imageUrl}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 18,
          height: 18,
          child: Image(
            image: NetworkImage(
                'https://cdn.sportmonks.com/images/soccer/leagues/5.png'),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        Flexible(
          child: new Text(
            name,
            style:
                new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it isn't work on chrome but work on the android emulator

Comment: I do have similar kind of web url and it's not working for the iPhone real device do we have any clues for the same?

Answer (score 31):

So flutter web has upgraded default rendered(HTML) -> CanvasKit and it has better performance.

You are most likely getting this error because CORS(can check chrome network tab to be sure).

To solve it could:

1. Update cors settings server side: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66104543/4679965
2. Run app with old rendered:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html // to run the app

flutter build web --web-renderer html --release // to generate a production build
```

3. Or display images with platform view:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

class MyImage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String imageUrl = "image_url";
    // https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41563
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      imageUrl,
      (int _) => ImageElement()..src = imageUrl,
    );
    return HtmlElementView(
      viewType: imageUrl,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, particularly for the number 3. In case anyone gets "Set style.height to any appropriate value to stop this message.", warning message then the solution is: ```(int _) => ImageElement()
        ..src = imageUrl
        ..style.width = '100%'
        ..style.height = '100%',```

Answer (score 17):

I get the same error, for a couple of weeks now, when trying to run an app from the **master** channel.

I got it working by forcing the web renderer to be HTML:

```
flutter run -d chrome --no-sound-null-safety --web-renderer=html
```

When you build your app for web you should:

```
flutter build web --no-sound-null-safety --web-renderer=html
```

By default the web renderer is **auto**, choosing the **canvaskit** web renderer on desktop browsers and **html** on mobile.

If you want to avoid this altogether you can stay on the **beta** or **dev** channels.

Comment: i changed to dev and tried to run with that but it failed, for now I'm working with the emulator but i hope it will be fixed because i want web too.

Comment: Use the **--web-renderer** argument and it should work.

Comment: it is working, there is a way to do that with debug?

Comment: Flutter runs by default in debug mode. The command **flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer=html** should be running your app into the Chrome web browser in debug mode.

Comment: You can find here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images the explanation of why it won't work without the **html** web renderer. You also have other solutions there.

Answer (score 1):

if it is working with another image then it should be a server-side error where the image is stored.

Comment: But you can enter the URL and the image is shown so how it is server-side error?

Comment: its not your fault

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble on flutter web place this on the `html` head and then clear your browser cache

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to define height, width for container and add fit:BoxFit.cover as a parameter of NetworkImage

Comment: Your solution won't work and the reason + a couple of solutions that work, including the one that I gave, can be found here:  https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images

Comment: it worked for me without changing the renderer

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with the codec format. Try running the same code with another image url. If it is working, then the above error could be a technical glitch.

You could try this widget

https://pub.dev/packages/meet_network_image

Comment: With another image URL it is working, what you mean by technical glitch.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to load images from my Firebase storage in Flutter and got this issue because CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) hadn't been set up on my Firebase storage. I followed the steps in outlined in this [guide](https://bitmovin.com/docs/encoding/faqs/how-do-i-set-up-cors-for-my-google-cloud-storage-bucket) to set CORS for my firebase storage and it resolved my problem. I'm sure there are similar guides on how to set it up on whatever file hosting platform you might be using for your images.

Answer (score 0):

As some answers suggested this issue is because of the canvas renderer.

You can follow this link to get the script you can add instead of running the renderer command for building/testing.

It worked for me!

https://phongyewtong.medium.com/flutter-web-image-network-not-loading-but-url-is-correct-e1dd3cd0d79f

Answer (score -1):

You can just use this package https://pub.dev/packages/image_network

Using HTML renderer might break other things (like SVG rendering in my case)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32448578)