# Unable to load network image of a YouTube thumbnail Flutter Web

Tags: image, flutter, dart, web, networking

I am trying to implement the Youtube Plyr IFrame plugin in my latest Flutter project( https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_plyr_iframe). Everything works expect I am unable to fetch the video thumbnail from the website source (https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/TyimCGEkiUc/maxresdefault.jpg). I've narrowed the problem down to the Image.network constructor. I am able to load other images with this widget but whenever it comes to a YouTube thumbnail it gives me this error:

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following ImageCodecException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Failed to load network image.
Image URL: https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/TyimCGEkiUc/maxresdefault.jpg
Trying to load an image from another domain? Find answers at:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
Image provider: NetworkImage("https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/TyimCGEkiUc/maxresdefault.jpg", scale: 1)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/TyimCGEkiUc/maxresdefault.jpg", scale: 1)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I am not sure what to make of this. The odd thing is that the example page featured in the Flutter package works fine, see here (https://jonatadashi.github.io/Web-Example/#/). If my problem wasn't frustrating enough I messed with the Interactive example on flutter.dev putting my link into the existing code and it worked completely fine (https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image). The Youtube Plyr IFrame package does not require any API and I am able to pull the image successfully in a basic html file.

My Code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Image.network(
            'https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/TyimCGEkiUc/maxresdefault.jpg'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is an image url that works with my code: https://picsum.photos/250?image=9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by using html renderer. I cannot take credit for this however here is another Stack Overflow thread where I found the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66617476/14670765

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html // to run the app

flutter build web --web-renderer html --release // to generate a production build
```

Comment: This works but you have to do it every time you compile it, it is not optimal. It should be fully fixed but only does it at runtime

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Displaying images on the web](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images), this is probably due to CORS.

If you try to Debug your application using Google Chrome with `--disable-web-security` flag it should work.

1. Create a batch file containing the command to launch Google Chrome with `--disable-web-security`:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\Users\username\chrome-temp" %*
```

2. Create or update CHROME_EXECUTABLE environment variable to redirect to your batch file.

*Note: this might affect your tests and the behavior of your application between debug and release.*

ref: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46904