# image network flutter web

Tags: image, flutter, web, flutter-web

When I try to display a network image in Flutter Web using the following syntax, no image is shown:

```
NetworkImage(
  'https://api.hsgmoto.com/api/images/product/catalog/IP-800208.png',
)
```

On mobile, the same code will show an image.

Comment: maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653801/flutter-web-cant-load-network-image-from-another-domain

Comment: Try to run project using below command "flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html"

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of CanvasKit.
Either you should run using HTML web renderer

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```

Or check below code.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49725#issuecomment-581052213

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following, in your index.html file and the images will start appearing,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
```