# How to use getBlob() to download a zip file from cloud storage?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase 10.8.0, developing locally with the emulator suite. I have a cloud function that generates an zip file, and now I'm attempting to build a client function that downloads the file to their local drive.

Here's what I've tried..

```
const handleDownload = () => {
  // Call the downloadPosts() endpoint
  // This cloud function creates the .zip file
  // The path to the file is returned in the response
  downloadPosts({ authorId: userId, includeTrashedPosts: includeTrashed })

    // Get the response
    // Call getBlob() to download the file
    .then((response) => {
      const { filepath } = response.data
      const fileRef = ref(storage, filepath)
      return getBlob(fileRef, 100000)
    })
    .then((blob) => {
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      window.location.replace(url)
    })
}
```

When I run this function, I'm simply redirected to a web page that looks like this

[image]

I have read the [docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_directly_from_the_sdk) and tried to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73671847/2146894).

Additionally, here is my file in the Storage console of the Emulator Suite. I am able to download it manually from here.

[image]

Comment: That looks like the contents of a zip file at first glance, so the contents seem correct. Is it that you want the data to be saved to a local file? If so, I see quite some relevant results in https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+download+file+from+firebase+storage+in+javascript

Comment: Please do edit the question to say more about what you want the result to be that's different than what you've observing now.  The code you have now looks like it's doing exactly what it's supposed to.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've edited my question, but in case it's still not clear, I want the user to be able to download the zip file to their local hard drive. Right now, my code just presents the user with a page of gibberish. (Note that I can download the zip file successfully (manually) from the storage console in the emulator suite.)

Comment: I removed the `maxDownloadSizeBytes` argument from `getBlob()` and now it works. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like fetching the entire blob solved your problem, but you may want to use an anchor element to download the file instead of `window.location.replace`. The advantages are it 1) allows you to name the file, and 2) doesn't redirect your page, just in case if the server returns an incomplete or nonzip file.

It looks something like:

```
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  let a = document.createElement('a')
  a.download = 'filename.zip'
  a.href = url
  a.click()
```

Altogether:

```
const handleDownload = () => {
  // Call the downloadPosts() endpoint
  // This cloud function creates the .zip file
  // The path to the file is returned in the response
  downloadPosts({ authorId: userId, includeTrashedPosts: includeTrashed })

    // Get the response
    // Call getBlob() to download the file
    .then((response) => {
      const { filepath } = response.data
      const fileRef = ref(storage, filepath)
      return getBlob(fileRef, 100000)
    })
    .then((blob) => {
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      let a = document.createElement('a')
      a.download = 'filename.zip'
      a.href = url
      a.click()
      // may want need to put this in a timeout if the blob is too big:
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
    })
}
```

See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328891/

[Download File Using JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3749231/) (A lot of the answers append the anchor element to the body, but from my experience, you don't actually have to attach it to DOM)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, kind of. Changing `getBlob(fileRef, 100000)` to `getBlob(fileRef)` made it work properly.