# How to specify build arguments for 'firebase deploy' command used for hosting

Tags: flutter, web, hosting, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I am using firebase hosting to host my flutter web app. Everytime I run `firebase deploy` or `flutter deploy --only hosting`, it builds the web app using `flutter build web`. How to give arguments to `flutter build web` here.

While deploying, I want to build my app with these arguments : `flutter build web --web-renderer html --release` to solve network image error.

OR

Is there any way I can tell firebase deploy to stop running `flutter build web` and just use existing build which I created using the arguments of my choice.

Answer (score 1):

Without using firebase experimental support for Flutter in the latest versions of firebase-cli, we used to run

`flutter build web --renderer canvaskit`

Then in `firebase.json` file, specify the directory where your HTML files are located using `public` json key.

I'm looking for a way to specify the --renderer param in the `firebase deploy` command.

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "site": "site-name",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```