# Firebase storage doesn't the image that's linked in flutter web

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I am trying to show my image in the image widget in Flutter. It is so simple function. But I tried even too many things. It does not work. I opened a FirebaseStorage section and I activated it. I call my Firebase functions to download the URL. But The images is not showing in my widget. I tried break the firebase version in dart section. But It is not still working. How can I fix it?

Here is the my published image link: (It works in browser but not in flutter web app)
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/commerce-fe056.appspot.com/o/mail.png?alt=media&token=6f57a585-25ae-44c9-ad12-15efea5d9163

Here is my version numbers:

```
 firebase_core: ^2.17.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.9.3
  firebase_auth: ^4.10.1
  firebase_storage: ^11.5.5
  cached_network_image: ^3.3.1
```

Here is my function codes:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Set the initial value of imageUrl to an empty string
    imageUrl = '';
    imageUrl1 = '';
    //Retrieve the imge grom Firebase Storage
    getImageUrl();

  }


  Future<void> getImageUrl() async {
    // Get the reference to the image file in Firebase Storage
    final ref = storaged.ref().child("mail.png");
    final ref1 = storaged.ref().child("files/faild.png");
    // Get teh imageUrl to download URL
    final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    final url1 = await ref1.getDownloadURL();
    setState(() {
      imageUrl = url;
      imageUrl1 = url1;
    });
  }
```

Lastly, here is my widgets:

```
 CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: imageUrl,
      placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
    ),




    SizedBox(
        height: 300,
        child: Image(
          image: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        )),
    Card(
      child: SizedBox(
          height: 300,
          child: Image(
            image: NetworkImage(imageUrl1 , ),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )),
    ),
```

[image]

Also, You can check my console :

[image]

Comment: What is the error in the debug console?

Comment: I am loading. Wait a minute please. Ok. I editted my question.

Comment: İ loaded. İf it is not enough clear for you. Just say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation on Displaying images on the web.](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/web-images)

Specifically, the [CORS section](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/web-images#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors):

> ... it is designed such that, by default, one web-site is not allowed to make HTTP requests to another site using XHR or fetch. This prevents scripts on another site from acting on behalf of the user and from gaining access to another site’s resources without permission.

---

One solution, [as discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66617476/12349734), would be to use HTML renderer. So, run the project within the Terminal:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html // to run the app

flutter build web --web-renderer html --release // to generate a production build
```

---

```dart
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final imageUrl =
      'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/commerce-fe056.appspot.com/o/mail.png?alt=media&token=6f57a585-25ae-44c9-ad12-15efea5d9163';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: imageUrl,
            placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

---

I'd recommend reading the above links that I have shared.

Comment: İ am so glad for helping. Gratefull all my heart. Thanks.

Comment: İ wanna ask you something. My firebase storage download and upload is not still working. Your solution will work on this problem ?

Comment: @BerkayIsıkoglu Not sure, I haven't really dealt with it. I'd recommend opening a _new_ question here on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

Using HTML renderer as @MendelG suggested indeed mitigates the problem with CORS. However, [HTML renderer is much worse in performance](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/renderers) and it's visible clearly in more complex screens that they don't run in 60FPS.

Since you're managing your Firebase Storage, I recommend to set up the CORS settings properly, you can read more on that e.g. here: [Firebase Storage and Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin)