# Image from firebase not showing on web in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have stored the image in to storage and the transfered the image in to firestore, but while trying to show the image Another exception was thrown: [object ProgressEvent] this error is showing up.
iam providing necessary code for more clarification

```
   child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: filteredStudents.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final DocumentSnapshot studentSnap =
                              snapshot.data.docs[index];

    child: ClipOval(
                        child: Image.network(
                        studentSnap['image url'],
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                         ),
                         ),
                        ),
```

i tried to display the image from firebase an iam expected to display particular image from firebase according to the index

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase storage doesn't the image that's linked in flutter web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77742800/firebase-storage-doesnt-the-image-thats-linked-in-flutter-web)

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77773703/14360762

Answer (score 0):

The error `[object ProgressEvent]` typically occurs when there is an issue with `fetching or loading` an image from a `network source`. In your case, it seems like you're trying to load images from Firebase Storage using the URLs stored in Firestore.

Here are a few things you can check and adjust:

1. Make sure that the URL you're using to fetch the image is correct
2. Ensure that the Firestore document contains the correct URLs for the              images
3. Implement error handling for the Image.network widget. If there's an issue with loading the image, it's better to show a placeholder or an error message. The errorBuilder parameter of Image.network can be used for this purpose.

   ```
   child: Image.network(
   studentSnap['image url'],
   fit: BoxFit.cover,
   errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
   return Text(error.toString());  },),
   ```

This will help you identify the root cause of the problem and take appropriate action.

Comment: i have checked the url and its directing me to the correct image. But when it comes to debugging, the image is not being shown

Comment: If possible, can you share some of the urls.