# Screenshot download issue in Flutter Web on mobile

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I'm building a web app in Flutter that gets images in from Firebase storage, lays the theme out on a canvas, takes a screenshot, and then downloads the screenshot. I'm running into a problem with the screenshot bit.

After some issues I got it to work on desktop but then it broke when it came to the mobile browser.

- When I use the `web --release` build the screenshot part doesn't work but the `Firebase Storage` part works
- When I use the `--web-renderer canvaskit` build the screenshot part works but the `Firebase Storage` part breaks. I get this error `[firesbase_storage/channel-error] Unable to establish connection on channel`;
- When I use the `--web-renderer html` build the screenshot part doesn't work but the `Firebase Storage` part works (after some extra work from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77742800/firebase-storage-doesnt-the-image-thats-linked-in-flutter-web)).

I'm not what the problem is now