# How to read excel file from Google cloud Storage to Jupyter notebook/ Jupyter lab using Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, google-cloud-platform, jupyter

```
'''
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
! pip install google-cloud
! pip install google-cloud-vision
! pip install gcsfs
df= pd.read_excel('gs://bank-modelling-project//training_data.xlsx')
df
'''
```

Error:     HttpError: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object., 401

1. Im using free trial account
2. I made the bucket as Public

Still im gettting the above error , Anybody can save my time here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gsutil ServiceException: 401 Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to bucket even though I'm loggedin in gcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302859/gsutil-serviceexception-401-anonymous-caller-does-not-have-storage-objects-list)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions#object_permissions), in order to be able to read from an Object stored in Google Cloud Storage, you need to have the proper permissions. In your case it is the: `storage.objects.get`.

In GCP, [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) are by between services to communicate between each other in the cloud with the right permissions. Thus, the Jupyter notebook uses a service account to access the object `gs://bank-modelling-project//training_data.xlsx` in GCS. So it needs the            `storage.objects.get` permission to read the object.

Below are the steps to assign this permission to your service account:

1. Go to your notebooks instance page and click on the instance you are using;
2. Under ***Instance properties***, check the *Service account*;
3. Now go to **IAM & ADMIN** and find the service account you saw in the previous step;
4. On the same line as its name, click on the Pencil icon to **edit the member**;
5. Add the pre-defined role Storage Object Viewer, because this role has the permission you need, such as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles).
6. Re-open your notebook instance and you will be able to read the GCS object you desire.

*Please note that you won't be able to create any object in GCS with only this permission.*