# Copy a folder from Google Cloud to the local server

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a folder in my GCP account and want to copy it to my directory in the local server. I did search to find a command to do that in the cloud shell or in my computer terminal but did not find anything. Could anybody help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: I believe this has been answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/76437628

Comment: Or if you're experiencing a specific issue it'd be great to see what you've tried in your question!

Comment: Thanks for the instruction. I used gsutil -m cp -r gs://bucket-name "{path to local existing folder}" in the cloud shell   but received this error CommandException: Destination URL must name a directory, bucket, or bucket
subdirectory for the multiple source form of the cp command.

Comment: What I added as the destination was: Username@URL:path-to-local-folder

Comment: I used this link and figured out I should use the terminal in my computer instead of the Google Could Shell to run the command. Using that and running the command "gsutil -m cp -r gs://bucket-name /Users/Username/Documents" I got this error: ServiceException: 401 Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.objects.list' denied on resource (or it may not exist).  Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I ran this "gcloud auth login" and this resolved the issue. Thanks @Jason R Stevens CFA

Answer (score 1):

Google provides two command line tools to manage Google Cloud Storage:

- gsutil - older and long established
- gcloud - storage features were recently added. Recommended tool today.

For example, to copy all files from a folder recursively:

- `gsutil cp -r gs://bucket-name/folder1/folder_to_copy /path-to-new-folder`
- `gcloud storage cp -r gs://bucket-name/folder1/folder_to_copy /path-to-new-folder`

[Documentation for gsutil cp](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)

[Documentation for gcloud storage cp](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage/cp)

Both tools are installed as part of the Google Cloud CLI:

[Install the CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install)

Comment: Thank you! I don't want to transfer the folder within Google Cloud but from Google cloud to the existing local machine.

Comment: My example commands copy from Google to the local machine.

Comment: Thanks! I used both commands and received this error "Destination URL must name an existing directory". What I added as the destination was: Username@URL:path-to-local-folder. I tried the destination with one of my computer folder instead of the folder in the sever but received the same error. I have tried these commands in the cloud shell of my bucket.

Comment: If the destination directory does not exist, create the directory. Note that you must also specify valid path names for the operating system. Using names like this ` Username@URL:path-to-local-folder` is not valid on most operating systems. That convention is used for remote systems such as FTP and SSH and not to specify local path names.

Comment: Thanks @John Hanley. The problem was that I used Cloud terminal instead of my computer terminal. Using this terminal and running the "gcloud auth login" command to give the authorization, I was able to run the gsutil -m cp -r gs://bucket-name "{path to local existing folder}" command.